# Admin's delete user link not working with Devise and Rails 7

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I want to allow admins to delete users from a link on the users index.

Desired behavior: When logged in admin clicks "delete" next to a username on the index page, that admin sees a confirmation message. Upon confirming, the user is deleted, admin sees updated index with flash success message.

I've tried two different ways, both failing. All things being equal, I'd prefer to do this using Devise out of the box functionality (e.g. the user_registration_path destroy action, and default flash message).

**First way - adding a destroy action to custom user controller:**

users/index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h2>All users</h2>

<%= will_paginate %>

  <ul class="users">
    <%= render @users %>
  </ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

users/_user.html.erb

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && current_user != user %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, data: { "turbo-method": :delete,
                                          turbo_confirm: "You sure?" } %>

  <% end %>
</li>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url, status: :see_other
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  root "static_pages#home"
  get "/about", to: "static_pages#about"
  get "/contact", to: "static_pages#contact"
  resources :users
end
```

Using this code, when I click "delete" next to the username, the user show page is loaded with these params:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"3"} permitted: false>
```

**Second way - using the destroy action in the registrations_controller:**

users/_user.html.erb

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && current_user != user %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user_registration_path, data: { "turbo-method": :delete,
                                          turbo_confirm: "You sure?" } %>

  <% end %>
</li>
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:destroy]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

  # The path used after sign up.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)
    user_url(@user)
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

Using this code, when I click "delete" next to the username, the users index page is reloaded with params:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

`<%= button_to "Delete user", user, form: {data: { turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }}, method: :delete %>`

Comment: The above solution doesn't work for me. In another place in the app I tried similar code, still not getting confirmation dialogue:

    <%= button_to "Delete park", @park, method: :delete,
        class: "btn btn-danger",
        form: { data: { "turbo_confirm": "Are you sure?" } } %>

Also, using link_to instead of button_to doesn't delete the record at all. Not sure if that's relevant.